# Set default value in spinner as "Select"

Tags: java, android, arraylist, spinner, android-arrayadapter

How do we set "Select" (default value) in a spinner as the first value ? I have browsed through here, and haven't found any clear solution or haven't understood them. I am pasting my sample code below. Please suggest a solution or explaination based on the same for my understanding. Thanks !

This is my MainActivity :

```
int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.briefcase,
        R.drawable.butterfly, R.drawable.coffee, R.drawable.home, R.drawable.kids, R.drawable.monitoring};

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles),
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description), icons);
    spinner.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   }
```

And this is my Adapter below

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

Context c;
String [] titles;
String [] desc;
int [] icons;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, String [] desc, int [] imgs) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_row, R.id.titles, titles);
    this.c = context;
    this.titles = titles;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.icons = imgs;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.img_Icon.setImageResource(icons[position]);
    holder.tv_Titles.setText(titles[position]);
    holder.tv_Desc.setText(desc[position]);
    return row;
}
}

class MyViewHolder{
TextView tv_Titles;
TextView tv_Desc;
ImageView img_Icon;
public MyViewHolder(View v) {
    tv_Titles = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titles);
    tv_Desc= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    img_Icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icons);
}
}
```

My string array res :

```
<string-array name="titles">
    <item>Sunday</item>
    <item>Monday</item>
    <item>Tuesday</item>
    <item>Wednesday</item>
    <item>Thursday</item>
    <item>Friday</item>
    <item>Saturday</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="description">
    <item>This is Sunday</item>
    <item>This is Monday</item>
    <item>This is Tuesday</item>
    <item>This is Wednesday</item>
    <item>This is Thursday</item>
    <item>This is Friday</item>
    <item>This is Saturday</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: add "Select" as the first item in the array

Comment: thanks, i had figured that out earlier, but thought there  might be a better way ? can it be handled in some way using the setSelection() method ? If so, how can the setSelection() be handled ?

Comment: set selection() is used to set the default selected item by passing the position of item...so for that your item should be in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "Select" as the first item to titles array and in your CustomAdapter if row position is 0 then only set the `holder.tv_Titles.setText(titles[position]);` and make visibility of `older.img_Icon` and `holder.tv_Desc` to `GONE`. On click of any spinner item check if the clicked item position is 0 or not. If it's 0 then show error or ignore.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions !